# Flutter: Positional arguments must occur before named arguments. Try moving all of the positional arguments before the named arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried solving it but I can't find out what went wrong. All I did was add the `listener` argument in the `AuthButton` that is going to the onPressed. AuthButton is also give below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../widgets/buttons.dart';
import '../widgets/phonenumber_widget.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                ),
                const Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/icon/brand_logo.png'),
                  width: 250,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                const Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Color(0xFF191B32)),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                const Text(
                  'Please enter your phone number to login with OTP',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black26,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),

                //Button
                const PhoneNumberInput(),

                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                AuthButton(
                  text: 'Request OTP', listener: () {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/otp');}),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Text('or, login with ...'),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: const [
                      SocialAuthButton(text: 'assets/icon/logo-google-50.png'),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 30,
                      ),
                      SocialAuthButton(
                          text: 'assets/icon/logo-facebook-50.png'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const Text('New to Zigzag?'),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: const Text(
                        'Sign up',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.purple,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

AuthButton

```
class AuthButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function listener;

  const AuthButton({Key? key, required this.text, required this.listener})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          listener(),
        },
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 30),
        minWidth: double.infinity,
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share `AuthButton` too?

Comment: Dart 2.17 removed the requirement that positional arguments always precede named arguments.

Comment: @fsbelinda Sure. I'll add it right now.

Comment: @I.Antonov I don't think `AuthButton` is the problem because; I tried it and it worked fine. Try to read the error in the console again, Dart should have probably pointed out the file and line causing the error .

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your function definition, but as the error message describes, it may like

```dart
void test(String required, {String optional = "default"}) {}
```

you should call it like

```dart
test("aa", optional: "specified");
```

not

```dart
test(optional: "specified", "aa");
```

in which the `required` variable is a positional argument and optional is an optional named argument.